# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent raw query lists behaviour causing arrays to be returned instead of objects

Tags: php, arrays, eloquent, laravel-5

Please assist with Laravel 5.1 and a raw query. It seems in spite of all efforts still an array is returned instead of an object so I can't use the `lists` command.

The error I get is:

`Call to a member function lists() on array`

I followed a tutorial here:
https://laracasts.com/lessons/reports-and-graphs

From the 5.1 manual / upgrade:

> The lists Method
>
> The lists method now returns a Collection instance instead of a plain
>   array for Eloquent queries. If you would like to convert the
>   Collection into a plain array, use the all method:
>
> **> User::lists('id')->all(); Be aware that the Query Builder lists method
>   still returns an array.**

My code:

```
public function index()
{
    //DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
    //DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
    $daily = DB::table('tasks')
    ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), DB::raw('count(id) as total'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
    ->get();

    dd($daily);

   return View::make('admin.reports.daily')
   ->with([
   'dates' => $daily->lists('date'),
   'totals' => $daily->lists('total')
   ]);
}
```

I have tried every single iteration of ->all() and ->toArray() but it still doesn't work.

DD outputs this:

> array:13 [▼ 0 => {#220 ▼
>   +"date": "2015-06-19"
>   +"total": 7 } 1 => {#221 ▼
>   +"date": "2015-06-20"
>   +"total": 4 } 2 => {#222 ▼
>   +"date": "2015-06-22"
>   +"total": 25 } 3 => {#223 ▶} 4 => {#224 ▶} 5 => {#225 ▶} 6 => {#226 ▶} 7 => {#227 ▶} 8 => {#228 ▶} 9 => {#229 ▶} 10 => {#230 ▶} 11 => {#231
>   ▶} 12 => {#232 ▶} ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query that is run using the query builder (`DB::table()...`) **returns an array and not a collection**. That means it has no `lists()` method. Actually no methods to call at all, since it is no object.

That isn't a too big problem though, you can just use `array_pluck`, which is used by the collection class as well:

```
return View::make('admin.reports.daily')
           ->with([
               'dates' => array_pluck($daily, 'date'),
               'totals' => array_pluck($daily, 'total')
           ]);
```

Comment: thank you. @dynamic's answer which was given first also worked, but your method is quicker. Incidentally to get the JSON encoded properly I had to use `{!!` instead of `{{` otherwise I got `&quot;`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `DB::table()->select()` that by default returns an array of php `stdClass` objects

Instead, when you use a method on a model, e.g. `User::method()` you will get objects of the `App\User` class

If you need to get an array of a single column after you run `DB::get` you can do:

```
$dates = [];
foreach($daily as $d)
 $dates[]=$d->date;
```

and then:

```
->with([
   'dates' => $dates
    ...
```

### Using FETCH_ASSOC

Note that if you use:

```
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then you can simplify the above code in:

```
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$daily = DB::table('tasks')
->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), DB::raw('count(id) as total'))
->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
->get();

//dd($daily);

 return View::make('admin.reports.daily')
   ->with([
   'dates' => array_column($daily,'date'),
   'totals' => array_column($daily,'total')
   ]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I understood it due to using `groupBy` and `DATE` casting in the MySQL I am forced to use `->select`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: you are simply missing the fact that db::get simply returns an array. So you can't apply a method on an array in PHP. Now if you need to extract only a single columns simply follow my suggest in the answer that I just edited